# Tensor Product is associative, distributive, not commutative.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

> Tensor Product is associative, distributive, not commutative.

Here is my attempt to show tensor product is associative, is it legit?

If $T$ is a $p$-tensor and $S$ a $q$ tensor, then $T \otimes S$ is a $p+q$ tensor:
$$T \otimes S(v_1, \ldots, v_p, v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}) = T(v_1, \ldots, v_p) \cdot S(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}).$$
Now consider a third tensor, a $r$-tensor $U$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & (T \otimes S ) \otimes U (v_1, \ldots, v_p, v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}, v_{p+q+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q+r})\\
&= &(T \otimes S (v_1, \ldots, v_{p+q})) \cdot U(v_{p+q+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q+r})\\
&= &T (v_1, \ldots, v_{p}) \cdot S(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}) \cdot U(v_{p+q+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q+r})\\
&= &T (v_1, \ldots, v_{p}) \cdot (S(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}) \cdot U(v_{p+q+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q+r}))\\
&= &T (v_1, \ldots, v_{p}) \cdot (S \otimes U (v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q+r}))\\
&= &T \otimes (S \otimes U)(v_1, \ldots, v_{p+q+r}).
\end{eqnarray*}

> Distributivity - is this proof legit?

First note that tensor product distribute over addition. If $T$ is a $p$-tensor and $S, U$ a $q$ tensor. Then I need to show that
$$ T \otimes (S + U) = (T \otimes U) + (S \otimes U).$$

Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&T \otimes (S + U)(v_1, \ldots, v_p, v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q})\\
& =& T (v_1, \ldots, v_p) \cdot (S + U)(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q})\\
& =& T (v_1, \ldots, v_p) \cdot (S (v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}) + U(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}))\\
& =& T (v_1, \ldots, v_p) \cdot S (v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}) +  T(v_1, \ldots, v_p) \cdot U(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q})\\
& =& (T \otimes S) + (T \otimes U)
\end{eqnarray*}

> It is not commutative - is this legit?

\begin{eqnarray*}
& & T \otimes S(v_1, \ldots, v_p, v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q})
 = T(v_1, \ldots, v_p) \cdot S(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q})\\
&= &S(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}) \cdot T(v_1, \ldots, v_p) = S \otimes T(v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}, v_{1}, \ldots, v_{p})\\
& \neq & S \otimes T(v_1, \ldots, v_p, v_{p+1}, \ldots, v_{p+q}).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Pay special attention to the indices in the very last line.

Comment: Thanks so much @anno. I guess I resolved the last question (turned into asking if it is legit. Thanks!)

Comment: More importantly, is what I am trying to show for distributivity correct? Thanks @anno

Comment: Presumably show that $\otimes$ distributes over addition of tensors.

Comment: The correct identity for "tensor distributes over dot product" would be $T \otimes (S \cdot U)=(T \otimes S) \cdot (T \otimes U).$ Why is distributivity helpful? Consider taking the tensor product of a tensor and a linear combination of tensors.

Comment: @LokiClock Thank you very much. But it would not work at the last step of distributivity.

Comment: With the dot product, it shouldn't.

Comment: Hi @LokiClock - could you take a look at the question mark at the end of the proof of distributivity? I couldn't figure out where went wrong.. Thanks.

Comment: @MathSnail The law you're trying to prove there is not distributivity. Nor is it distributivity of the tensor product over addition - which would make the tensor product the multiplication of a ring over the vector space, if associativity also holds. Not that you couldn't try to prove it distributes over the dot product, but I'm not sure of the significance.